# MongoDB Iterate Over Given Timeframe

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was able to set up the following script which brings up the last time a user logged in closest to a given date and their battery level.

```
db.getCollection("_User").find().forEach( 

    function(myDoc) { var a = db.Data.find({user:
myDoc.username, "_created_at": {$lt: new ISODate("2017-09-17T23:25:56.314Z")} }).sort( { "
_created_at": -1 } ).limit(1)

  if( a.length() > 0){ print(a[0]["battery"])}

}
```

Now I want to encapsulate this for a given time frame say `2013-09-17T13:25:56.314Z` TO `2013-09-17T23:25:56.314Z` how would I go about doing that, and iterate each time in the loop by five minutes? I also want to store the information in a new collection.

I'm not familiar with databases so I'm doing this as it was more efficient that pulling stuff into `pandas` and putting it back on mongodb.

Comment: Do you want for this a user for all user when you rung the query ?

Comment: I want to do this for all users in _User yes

Comment: Can you give more detail about your Models. User and Data models for example. What are you trying to get.